# How to detect a change in an ng-model object inside a custom directive?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

Consider this [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/WKYPMS?p=preview) which has the behaviour I'm after.

The problem is that 1) I think I'm doing it wrong, and 2) it uses a deep watch, which is expensive and should be unnecessary.

The example is a bit contrived. What I actually have in my application is a fully featured typeahead/autocomplete control which binds to objects and renders them according to expressions. The plunker is stripped down to show only the parts that should be relevant to this question; **How to implement this sort of thing correctly?**

**The main difficulty is ensuring that entering "something" in the input and clicking the button should propagate into the directive and cause the `span.outlet` to update accordingly. Ie, clicking the Alpha, and attempting to change the description should lead to "Selected: A - something" showing on the page.**

If I remove the deep watch, this won't happen unless I replace the $scope.selected with a new object reference rather than just changing a property on the existing object reference (see comment in the mainCtrl of the plunker).

So, the first requirement is that the custom directive deals with objects, and not simply strings.

The second requirement is that the directive must be able to update the `span.outlet` whenever the `$scope.selected` object changes from outside of the custom directive.

Thirdly the directive should be as performant as possible. And this is why I'm raising the question. The ng-model allready has shallow $watch internally, and now I'm adding a deep $watch on top of it, which is bad for perf. Is there a way to do this without such a deep $watch?

Finally it would be nice if I didn't have to have a scope.ngModel binding. It feels dirty.

Relevant markup:

```
<input ng-model="newDescription">
<button ng-click="setNewDescription(newDescription)">Set description</button>
<hr/>
<my-list ng-model="selected" expression="{{::expression}}" options="options"></my-list>
```

Relevant main controller code:

```
  $scope.options = [
    {key:'A', desc: 'Alpha'},
    {key:'B', desc: 'Beta'},
    {key:'G', desc: 'Gamma'},
    {key:'D', desc: 'Delta'}
  ];
  $scope.selected = $scope.options[1];
  $scope.expression = '{{key}} - {{desc}}';
```

myList directive:

```
app.directive('myList', ['$interpolate', function($interpolate) {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    require: 'ngModel',
    replace: true,
    template: '<div>Selected: <span class="outlet"></span><ul><li ng-repeat="item in vm.items"><a href="" ng-click="vm.select(item)">{{vm.render(item)}}</a></li></ul></div>',
    scope: {
      ngModel: '=',
      items: '=options'
    },
    link: Link,
    controller: Ctrl,
    controllerAs: 'vm',
    bindToController: true 
  };

  function Link(scope, element, attrs, ngModelCtrl) {
     var outlet = element.children()[0];
     scope.vm.render = $interpolate(attrs.expression);

     ngModelCtrl.$formatters.push(function(modelValue) {
       if (ngModelCtrl.$isEmpty(modelValue))
            return '';
        else
            return scope.vm.render(modelValue);
     });

     ngModelCtrl.$render = function() {
       console.log('rendering', ngModelCtrl.$viewValue);
       outlet.textContent = scope.vm.render(ngModelCtrl.$modelValue);
     };

    ngModelCtrl.$parsers.push(function(value) {
        // Only gets called due to the $setViewValue call in the deep $watch.
        // We don't have a way of going from a string to an object, but the $modelValue contains the right thing.
        console.log('parsing', value);
        return ngModelCtrl.$modelValue;
    });

    // I would prefer it if I could solve this without a deep watch on ngModel!
    scope.$watch('vm.ngModel', function(n, o) {
      if (angular.equals(n, o)) return;
      console.log('ngModel $watch\r\n', o, '->\r\n', n);
      ngModelCtrl.$setViewValue(scope.vm.render(n));
      ngModelCtrl.$render();
    }, true); 
  }

  function Ctrl($scope) {
    this.select = function(item) {
      console.log('selecting', item);
      this.ngModel = item;
    }.bind(this);
  }
}]);
```

Any help with this is much appreciated as I've been trying to wrap my head around this problem for a while now. Thanks!

Comment: I'd love more information on what your myList directive should do. As you said you're probably doing it wrong so having the final objective (the list purpose and behaviours) would help a lot.

Comment: Dunno if this will help but i made the same behaviour without any directive just using a simple ng-repeat. That involves no $watch no $ng-model etc ... http://plnkr.co/edit/DmlTyOWki3fB1WowAxpy?p=preview

Comment: @Okazari As I said, it's an autocomplete directive which uses a promise-based lookup store. However I don't want to run a lookup (which often is a server-call) when simply rendering my document model. Hence I store the full object instead of only the key on the document model. Furthermore the merging of changesets is the core thing. I'm updating the directive model without replacing the object. What other information may I provide? Can you be specific about what it is you need to know? Thanks!

Comment: @Okazari Sorry, no, the whole point is to have an encapsulated directive unit using an ng-model. I need validation etc to work as well which means there must be an ng-model bound to selected.

Comment: Actually you can apply validation on variable that arent bind to a ng-model. Could you explain what you try to do without talking about the technical part ? I mean you here try to do some really complex things and in my experience with angular ifs something seems complex to do. It's just cause it is not the way to do it. I would like to know about why you need this directive.

Comment: @Okazari Mainly I'm trying to modify the ng-model both from outside and inside the directive. That's not the main scenario, and I believe that's why this is complex. I added something to the description to explain what's failing when/if I simplify.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79542/discussion-between-okazari-and-mithon).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some discussion with @Okazari I was able to at least get rid of the deep watch by replacing it with a function watch which is rendering the model according the the expression.

```
scope.$watch(function() {
  return scope.vm.render(scope.vm.ngModel);
}, function(n, o) {
  if (n && n !== o) {
    console.log('ngModel $watch\r\n', o, '->\r\n', n);
    ngModelCtrl.$setViewValue(scope.vm.render(n));
    ngModelCtrl.$render();
  }
});
```

I'm still not confident I'm doing this the right way. But at least it's a way that works, for now.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure that I completely understand your needs, but I prepared [sample](http://plnkr.co/edit/Vc1mvRe5GixqJACXH3sw?p=preview)

```
app.directive('myList', ['$interpolate', function($interpolate) {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    replace: true,
    template: '<div>Selected: <span class="outlet"></span><ul><li ng-repeat="item in vm.items"><a href="" ng-click="vm.select(item)">{{vm.render(item)}}</a></li></ul></div>',
    scope: {
      selected: '=',
      items: '=options'
    },
    link: Link,
    controller: Ctrl,
    controllerAs: 'vm',
    bindToController: true 
  };

  function Link(scope, element, attrs, ctrl) {
     var outlet = element.children()[0];
     scope.vm.render = $interpolate(attrs.expression);

    scope.$watch(function () {
      return ctrl.selected;
    }, function (value) {
      console.log('rendering', value);
      outlet.textContent = scope.vm.render(value);
    });
  }

  function Ctrl($scope) {
    this.select = function(item) {
      console.log('selecting', item);
      this.selected = item;
    }.bind(this);
  }
}]);
```

Html:

```
 <input ng-model="newDescription">
 <button ng-click="setNewDescription(newDescription)">Set description</button>
 <hr/>
 <my-list selected="selected" expression="{{::expression}}" options="options"></my-list>
```

**Update 2**

[Sample](http://plnkr.co/edit/zWC1Cb21o4asenTc3BqL?p=preview) with `ng-model`. You don't need to call $render function in $watch. It's called after model changing automatically.

Also the good example how to create directive with ngModel [here](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-date/blob/master/src/date.js).

Comment: Sorry, it doesn't updated the outlet when clicking 'Set description'. It does if I change the watch to be a deep watch (by adding true as a third param) But the extra deep watch is what I want to avoid.

Comment: Your sample still doesn't work. It's not updating the span.outlet when clicking the button. I updated the question with information of this main point.

Comment: Thanks for the link to the ui-date directive. I'll look closely at that.

Comment: So, I tested the ui-date directive. It doesn't solve my issue. If you bind a ui-date to a $scope.theDate = new Date() and then change it through a $scope.theDate.setDate(otherDate), then the component won't update. Which is exactly the problem I'm having.

Comment: It does however work when you bind it to a date string instead. But that's not my scenario.